# Tabhost, android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window

Tags: java, android

Hello In my app i am using TabHost

http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html

now in that i am opening twitter tab, facebook tab page in webview, it is loaded successfully but at login time if i press login button after passing **username and password** the app crashes and following error will occur.

```
   02-28 18:58:17.519: E/AndroidRuntime(10604): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@4051ec60 is not valid; is your activity running?
   02-28 18:58:17.519: E/AndroidRuntime(10604):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:528)
   02-28 18:58:17.519: E/AndroidRuntime(10604):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
   02-28 18:58:17.519: E/AndroidRuntime(10604):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
   02-28 18:58:17.519: E/AndroidRuntime(10604):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:465)
   02-28 18:58:17.519: E/AndroidRuntime(10604):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
   02-28 18:58:17.519: E/AndroidRuntime(10604):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:813)
   02-28 18:58:17.519: E/AndroidRuntime(10604):     at android.webkit.WebView.onSavePassword(WebView.java:1123)
   02-28 18:58:17.519: E/AndroidRuntime(10604):     at android.webkit.CallbackProxy.handleMessage(CallbackProxy.java:424)
   02-28 18:58:17.519: E/AndroidRuntime(10604):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   02-28 18:58:17.519: E/AndroidRuntime(10604):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
   02-28 18:58:17.519: E/AndroidRuntime(10604):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3835)
   02-28 18:58:17.519: E/AndroidRuntime(10604):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

my class for loading facebook page or twitter page is

```
    public class FacebookActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private WebView mWebView;
ProgressDialog PD;
String sabNZBurl;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.facebook);

    sabNZBurl = getResources().getString(R.string.fburl);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    // Added by Pankit -------- start
    if (!TabSample.checkForInternet.isNetworkAvailable(this, this)) {
        Toast.makeText(TabSample.tabContext,
                "No Net Connection... Exiting...", 2000).show();
        exitOnNoNetConnection();

    } else {

        // Added by Pankit -------- End
        PD = new ProgressDialog(TabSample.tabContext);
        PD.setMessage("Please Wait......");
        PD.show();
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl(sabNZBurl);
     }
}

   final class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onLoadResource(view, url);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        PD.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have almost the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ?

Comment: Yup i have found solution Shehabix :) just post question on stackoverflow i will give u answer and give me rattings

Comment: Siddhpura why don't you just post your solution? You suck so badly! Expecting others to help you but once you find the solution not to post it is so narrow minded!

Comment: @SiddhpuraAmit you can give your own question's answer here.